# How to solve a recurrence relation given an observed pattern

Tags: recurrence-relations

So I have the below recurrence relation.

[image: the difference of the delta values is 4x]

If you write out some terms you get the following

> a(0) = 2
>
> a(1) = 13
>
> a(2) = 57
>
> a(3) = 233
>
> a(4) = 937

the delta values are as follows

> a(0-1) = 11
>
> a(1-2) = 44
>
> a(2-3) = 176
>
> a(3-4) = 704

Simple algebra tells that you can find the next term by multiplying by 4 so the difference is 4x. Now my question is, how can I use this knowledge to find a closed form? The formula of a geometric sequence (a(n)=a(0)r^n) doesn't seem to work here and that's the most similar closed form formula I can think of.

Comment: Since you give no context as to what you know or can use about linear recurrences, the following might as well qualify as a hint: $$a_n+\frac{5}{3} = 4\left(a_{n-1} + \frac{5}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

If
$a_n = ua_{n-1}+v$,
then it looks like $a_n$
is about $u$ times $a_{n-1}$,
but not quite.

So,
let's see if we can perturb
$a_n$
to get something that does
get multiplied by $u$
each time.

The simplest perturbation
is by a constant.
So,
let
$a_n = b_n+c$.

Then
$a_n = ua_{n-1}+v$
becomes
$b_n+c = u(b_{n-1}+c)+v
=ub_{n-1}+uc+v
$
or
$b_n
=ub_{n-1}+uc+v-c
=ub_{n-1}+c(u-1)+v
$.

Therefore,
if we choose $c$ so that
$c(u-1)+v=0$,
or
$c = \dfrac{v}{1-u}$,
then
$b_n = ub_{n-1}$,
which is easy to solve.

The only case where
we can not do this is
$u=1$,
but in this case the recurrence is
$a_n = a_{n-1}+v$,
where $a_n$ grows linearly
rather than exponentially.

In all other cases,
we get
$b_n = u^nb_0$
or
$a_n-c
= u^n(a_0-c)$
or
$a_n 
= u^n(a_0-c)+c
= u^na_0-cu^n+c
$.